# Using distinct and order by in mysql, but it did not remove duplicate data

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct

I don't konw why it did't remove duplicate data when i execute the sql of

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    account_id
FROM
    t_profit_sum_archive
WHERE
    profit_id >= 52487444
ORDER BY
    profit_id
LIMIT 10000000;
```

This is the table of `account`.

```
profit_id  account_id     type   am   profit   date_settled      time_create    time_update
    1   4425211956666666666 4     0      0     2018-04-24   2018-05-15 10:57:21 2018-05-15 10:57:21
    2   5422433335611061810 4   3000000 340    2018-04-24   2018-05-15 10:57:21 2018-05-15 10:57:21
    3   3102301983522434928 4     0      0     2018-04-25   2018-05-15 10:57:21 2018-05-15 10:57:21
    4   4425211956666666666 4   3000000 340    2018-04-25   2018-05-15 10:57:21 2018-05-15 10:57:21
```

I really don't know why? 
  I guess maybe the reason is that the table has too much data(78926576 rows), 
 because when i test another table(230000 rows), it is ok.
The table structure is as follows:

```
profit_id   bigint  
account_id  varchar 
type    char    
am  bigint                  
profit  bigint  
date_settled    date    
time_create datetime    
time_update datetime
```

Comment: What data type is account_id?

Comment: it is varchar.  `profit_id bigint`
`account_id varchar` 
`type  char`
`am bigint`
`profit bigint`
`date_settled date`
`time_create datetime`
`time_update datetime`

Comment: Is it possible that one of the duplicate account ids has whitespace? Table size should not matter.

Comment: the account_id is not null or whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to remove all the duplicates then fetch the first 10000000 records.

```
SELECT 
   A.account_id
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
    account_id
FROM
    t_profit_sum_archive
WHERE
    profit_id >= 52487444
ORDER BY
    profit_id) A
LIMIT 10000000;
```

Comment: Maybe your answer is right, but if you put limit outside，its efficiency will be relatively low.

Comment: What are you trying to fetch with the query? Seems you want to counts the id as you commented on @LoztInSpace's answer.

Comment: This table is about investment. I want to count the ids and get the ids,because i need this ids to compare with another table.